# I get a permissions error when trying to open .msg file written with javax

Tags: java, outlook, fileoutputstream, jakarta-mail

Hi I am writing an email that has 2 attachments, one is another email & a text document. Everything works as expected after a few hours of research I cannot seem to fix one problem.

Ok, so I know that Outlook which is the program that the email will be opened in stores its emails using a .eml extension. After all the email building I write the attachment email to a tmp file like this.

```
            msg.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/"+contactName+".eml")));
```

My goal was to create a 'draft' like email where once you open it all fields like To, CC, Bcc, and subject are already available and editable. If I write it this way the only way to edit those fields is to open the attachment email and hit 'reply-all'. This extra step also includes deleting the text that gets generated like.

From: eolnotification@niksun.com [mailto:eolnotification@company.com]

Sent: Saturday, February 08, 2014 4:11 PM

Subject: NOTICE of End of Life Company products within 90 Days

So I figured out that instead of .eml I should use .msg. When I use this it seems to be a permission problem.

```
      msg.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/"+contactName+".msg")));
```

Cannot open file: C:\tmp\joe_susie.msg The file may not exist, you may not have permission to open it, or it may be open in another program. Right-click the folder that contains the file, and then click Properties to check your permissions for the folder.

I tried all different ways to change permission and nothing works. Someone said it's because of how the file is written to the outputstream. I even tried making a FileOutputStream object and explicitly closed it, that doesn't work either.

I know for a fact that a .msg does open editable how I want but with my code it's not working. Does anyone know about this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your program is not closing the FileOutputStream in the following line.

`msg.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/"+contactName+".eml")));`

You need to rewrite that as:

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/"+contactName+".eml"))) {
    msg.writeTo(fos);
    fos.flush();
}
```

For some reason the Outlook open dialog is not able to open a '.eml' file.  However, if you want to open a `.eml` (MIME text) file from outlook you can do so by used the undocumented '/eml' switch:

```
outlook.exe /eml foo.eml
```

If you want to open a '.msg' (binary) file from outlook you can do so by using the documented '/f' switch:

`outlook.exe /f foo.msg`